# Hikari CP connection to a local postgresql db: "Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections"

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, apache-storm, hikaricp

I'm creating a Storm project using Maven, in which I connected a local postgresql database using the HikariCP connection (version: 2.7.3), but it doesn't works. 
The postgresql database is created using pgAdmin III and PostgreSQL 9.5.
I'm using 1.1.1 storm version.

The same code in a java project runs.

```
package storm.topologies;

import org.apache.storm.jdbc.common.Column;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.common.ConnectionProvider;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.common.HikariCPConnectionProvider;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.common.JdbcClient;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.mapper.JdbcMapper;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.mapper.JdbcLookupMapper;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.mapper.SimpleJdbcMapper;
import org.apache.storm.jdbc.mapper.SimpleJdbcLookupMapper;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import itd.meter.storm.spouts.UserQueueSpout;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;

public abstract class AbstractUserTopology {



   private static final List<String> setupSqls = Lists.newArrayList(
            "create table if not exists table(x varchar(20), y varchar(20), id varchar(50))"
           );

    protected UserQueueSpout userQueueSpout;
    protected JdbcMapper jdbcMapper;
    protected JdbcLookupMapper jdbcLookupMapper;
    protected ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;

    protected static final String TABLE_NAME = "table";
    protected static final String JDBC_CONF = "jdbc.conf";

    String SELECT_QUERY ="select x,y from table where id ='01'";
    public void execute(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map hikariConfigMap = Maps.newHashMap();

        hikariConfigMap.put("jdbcUrl","jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MYDB");  

        hikariConfigMap.put("dataSource.user", "postgres");
        hikariConfigMap.put("dataSource.password", "password");
        hikariConfigMap.put("dataSource.portNumber", "5432");

        if (args.length == 4) {
            hikariConfigMap.put("dataSource.password", args[3]);//password
        }
        Config config = new Config();
        config.put(JDBC_CONF, hikariConfigMap);

        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new HikariCPConnectionProvider(hikariConfigMap);
        connectionProvider.prepare();

        //query timeout seconds param that specifies 
        //max seconds an insert query can take
        int queryTimeoutSecs = 60;

        JdbcClient jdbcClient = new JdbcClient(connectionProvider, queryTimeoutSecs);

        for (String sql : setupSqls) {
            jdbcClient.executeSql(sql);
        }
        this.userQueueSpout = new UserQueueSpout();
        this.jdbcMapper = new SimpleJdbcMapper(TABLE_NAME, connectionProvider);

        connectionProvider.cleanup();

        Fields outputFields = new Fields("x", "y","id");

        List<Column> queryParamColumns = Lists.newArrayList(new Column("x", Types.VARCHAR), new Column("y", Types.VARCHAR), new Column("id",Types.VARCHAR));

        this.jdbcLookupMapper = new SimpleJdbcLookupMapper(outputFields, queryParamColumns);
        this.connectionProvider = new HikariCPConnectionProvider(hikariConfigMap);

        if (args.length == 4) {
            config.setDebug(false);
            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology("stormProject", config, getTopology());

        } else {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[4], config, getTopology());
        }
    }

    public abstract StormTopology getTopology();

}
```

Below the error:

```
56999 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  o.a.s.j.c.HikariCPConnectionProvider - JDBC Url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MYDB
57014 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
57443 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  c.z.h.p.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Il metodo ½org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getNetworkTimeout()╗ non Þ stato ancora implementato.)
57474 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
57528 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
57543 [storm.topologies.TOPOLOGY.main()] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

how can it be resolved?

Comment: Here's some reading on the issue https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/638

Comment: However it's unclear if that has anything to do with the exception, network timeout not being implemented is just a warning.

Comment: What is this question reallu about? Are you asking about Hikari's 'warning'? Because that is something you can ignore (it is just informational). As far as I can tell, the exception has nothing to do with Hikari's warning, it looks like you are barking up the wrong tree here. It looks like the line triggering the error is `StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[4], config, getTopology());` which would mean `args` has a length smaller than 5.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I made a mistake thinking that the exception depended on the warning, but now I'm sure the Hikari CP warning can be ignored!

Comment: quite coincidentally, the Postgres JDBC project just accepted our pull request to implement network timeout yesterday.

Comment: Good news! I'll keep me updated.